# Статические методы или extends Application

Tags: android, производительность, static

В общем, в моем приложении есть много методов которые могут использоваться много раз в разных фрагментах(в одной активности).И тут я подумал а почему бы не создать один класс со всеми методами и переменными и сделать их статическими что-бы в нужный момент за них "дергать". Я на каком-то американском форуме читал, что это потенциальная причина утечек. И самому интересно засоряет ли это стек вызов(в книгах пишут что только во время вызовов засоряет). Кто-то может объяснить как это влияет на производительность и стоит так делать или нет? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Это называется [Божественный объект](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Божественный_объект), признанный антипаттерн.

Comment: создайте базовый фрагмент и наследуйтесь от него

Comment: @Style-7 обычный фрагмент с этими методами и просто наследовать? Тогда какая разница будет ли этот метод статический или наследован от от класса фрагмента?

Comment: @mrEvgenX не могли бы подсказать какую-то литературу что бы поближе познакомиться с петтернами и антипеттернами?)

Comment: В интернете поищите, пожалуйста, "паттерны проектирования" или как-то так, все есть :) к слову, если вы сделаете метод статическим, забудьте о полиморфизме, это не всегда уместно приносить в жертву, на все случаи жизни одного рецепта нет.

Answer (score 1):

На счёт много раз использовать одни и те же методы. Это напрашивается библиотека утилит. А то что объединить все в один класс вы уйдете от принципов SOLID, а конкретно от принципа единственной ответственности.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста поподробнее о библиотеке утилит.

Comment: Что именно вам интересно?

Comment: По сути это пакет util. В котором описаны классы и методы используемые как утилиты во всем приложении

Comment: Вы написали, что напрашивается библиотека утилит, а я даже не знаю что это)

Comment: И как она создаеться?

Comment: Можете написать библиотеку с классами?

Comment: добавить каталог utils тем самым отделить ваши классы утилиты в отдельный каталог